# How to use foreach with a hash reference?

Tags: perl, hash

I have this code

```
foreach my $key (keys %ad_grp) {

    # Do something
}
```

which works.

How would the same look like, if I don't have `%ad_grp`, but a reference, `$ad_grp_ref`, to the hash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the safest way to iterate through the keys of a Perl hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033/whats-the-safest-way-to-iterate-through-the-keys-of-a-perl-hash)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
foreach my $key (keys %$ad_grp_ref) {
    ...
}
```

`Perl::Critic` and daxim recommend the style

```
foreach my $key (keys %{ $ad_grp_ref }) {
    ...
}
```

out of concerns for readability and maintenance (so that you don't need to think hard about what to change when you need to use `%{ $ad_grp_obj[3]->get_ref() }` instead of `%{ $ad_grp_ref }`)

Comment: You'd get more upvotes from me if you taught better style:  [`keys %{ $ad_grp_ref }`](http://p3rl.org/Perl::Critic::Policy::References::ProhibitDoubleSigils)

Comment: that's not better, that's worse.   also, http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference can be very helpful

Comment: I fully agree with ysth, there's no reason to make an expression more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: `keys %$ad_grp_ref` is more readable, especially when surrounded by other circumfix operators.

Comment: As you can see, Sandra, There's More Than One Way To Do It.

Answer (score 8):

In Perl 5.14 (it works in now in Perl 5.13), we'll be able to just [use keys on the hash reference](http://www.dagolden.com/index.php/1161/whats-new-in-perl-5-13-7/)

```
use v5.13.7;

foreach my $key (keys $ad_grp_ref) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: you will need `use 5.14.0` or the like to be sure that your script doesn't attempt to run on Perl versions too old to use this syntax (or whatever 5.13.X this is allowed in of course).

Comment: Good point, I should have put that right in the code sample. Amended.

Comment: `Experimental keys on scalar is now forbidden`. This feature was removed in 5.22. (ish)

Answer (score 5):

As others have stated, you have to dereference the reference. The `keys` function requires that its argument starts with a *%*:

My preference:

```
foreach my $key (keys %{$ad_grp_ref}) {
```

According to [Conway](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596001738):

```
foreach my $key (keys %{ $ad_grp_ref }) {
```

Guess who you should listen to...

You might want to read through the [Perl Reference Documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

If you find yourself doing a lot of stuff with references to hashes and hashes of lists and lists of hashes, you might want to start thinking about using [Object Oriented Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html). There's [a lot of nice little tutorials](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html) in the Perl documentation.

Answer (score 4):

With Perl 5.20 the new answer is:

```
foreach my $key (keys $ad_grp_ref->%*) {
```

(which has the advantage of transparently working with more complicated expressions:

```
foreach my $key (keys $ad_grp_obj[3]->get_ref()->%*) {
```

etc.)

See [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Postfix-Dereference-Syntax) for the full documentation.

Note: in Perl version 5.20 and 5.22, this syntax is considered experimental, so you need

```
use feature 'postderef';
no warnings 'experimental::postderef';
```

at the top of any file that uses it.  Perl 5.24 and later don't require any pragmas for this feature.