# How to pull data from a JSON response in Perl

Tags: perl, reference, hashtable

I have a JSON response, which I need to process in Perl to extract information out of and do further processing. The JSON document looks like this:

```
{
  "SITE_1": [
    {
      "values": [
        {
           "time": 20170616100000,
           "v":    11
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "SITE_2": [
    {
      "values": [
        {
           "time": 20170616100000,
           "v":    12
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to process it in a subroutine using:

```
my ($ref) = @_;
foreach my $row (0..$#{$ref}) {
   $val = ${$ref}{$site}[0]{values}[0]{v}; 
   Prt('-O',"$val\n");    etc.. etc...
```

Getting the "Not an Array error" I think due to the first item in the JSON being in a { } not [ ].

What's the simplest way to parse the data?

Comment: This doesn't look like JSON

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JSON! In the future, please omit irrelevant details.

Comment: My apologies. I won't make the same mistake again. But thankyou for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use foreach with a hash reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5249362/100754) ... I've already voted to close for another reason, but I think linking to the duplicate would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking how to iterate over the elements of a hash?

```
for my $site (keys(%$ref)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! I am. And it worked. I combined it with a previous response to get to get exactly what I was after.

Comment: @BenHarrison [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)