# Replicable iteration over a hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash, iteration, replicate

It is well known how to iterate over a hash in perl (see, e.g., [What's the safest way to iterate through the keys of a Perl hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033/whats-the-safest-way-to-iterate-through-the-keys-of-a-perl-hash)). However, the order of the keys and values is undetermined and in fact different for each run of the perl script.

Is there a way to ensure that every run of the same perl script on the same input data results in the same iteration order? I only care for replicability in this sense---the order needs not to be predictable by a human being.

EDIT: I formulated the question in terms of iteration, but maybe it is not the iteration over the hash but the hash building process that is non-deterministic. Can I set some inititialisation to build the hash in a deterministic and replicable way?

Comment: `the order needs not to be predictable by a human being` how about the same order of keys as they were inserted into the hash?

Comment: @Сухой27: No problem, this order is as good as any **fixed** order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) them first:

```
foreach my $key (  sort keys %hash ) { 

}
```

Note: Default sort is alphabetical, not numeric. But `sort` will take a custom function to allow you to sort in almost any order you care to name.

Alternatively, capture the ordering in an array and use *that* to extract the output order.

```
my %content_for;
my @ordered_id; 

while ( <$input_filehandle> ) { 
    my ( $id, $content ) = split; 
    push ( @ordered_id, $id ); 
    $content_for{$id} = $content; 
}

print join ( "\n", @content_for{@ordered_id} ),"\n"
```

;

Or something like an ordered hash mechanism like `Hash::Ordered` or `Tie::IxHash`.

> I formulated the question in terms of iteration, but maybe it is not the iteration over the hash but the hash building process that is non-deterministic. Can I set some inititialisation to build the hash in a deterministic and replicable way?

No. Hashes don't work like that. See - [`perlsec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks) for an explanation why. It got *more* random with newer versions of perl, but it was always an unordered data structure.

You can perhaps mess around with (as mentioned in the article) [PERL_HASH_SEED](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#PERL_HASH_SEED) and [PERL_PERTURB_KEYS](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#PERL_PERTURB_KEYS) but this would definitely not be a good practice.

```
PERL_HASH_SEED=0 ./somescript.pl
```

But you should bear in mind that hash ordering is still not guaranteed - the sequencing of keys may still change. It'll be a bit more consistent than before though. This is definitely not a good thing to use in production, or rely on for anything more than debugging.

> PLEASE NOTE: The hash seed is sensitive information. Hashes are randomized to protect against local and remote attacks against Perl code. By manually setting a seed, this protection may be partially or completely lost.

Comment: :) you just beat me for few seconds :) `sort` is probably the only way to achieve this.

Comment: It's the easy answer, but there are others - like using `Hash::Ordered` which ... basically builds in a `sort`.

Comment: This is a good answer, but are there really no alternatives, like setting some initialisations to make the hash reproducible?

Comment: No. A hash is an unordered set of key-value pairs. This is because of how it's arranged in memory (for efficient random access). You can work with things that aren't hashes if you want, but you _cannot_ make magically make an unordered data structure ordered again.

Comment: With some digging - there is a debug mode that will let you do this to a degree. This would be a terrible idea to use in production code. Setting an environment var PERL_HASH_SEED=0

Comment: [Tie::Hash::Indexed](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Hash::Indexed) offers the same functionality as Tie::IxHash but is significantly faster.